# Using IPsec to secure traffic

Tags: security, ipsec

I have a client server environment and would like to secure the network traffic using IPsec. What is involved to get this implemented? The application is working fine, I just need to secure the traffic between computers.

What do I need - certificates on each computer for example? Do I need to make changes to the socket read/write code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since IPSec is implemented at the IP level, your application does not need to be changed for IPSec (and it will not notice anything about it).

What exactly is needed for IPSec depends - but you'd be better off asking this question on serverfault.

Comment: Thanks. Will repost at serverfault.